# PagedList.Mvc paging Lost when I filtered Products

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I am using PagedList.Mvc and when I make Filter Like 
localhost:2241/Samsung and go to page 2 
the browser redirect to localhost:2241/ instead of 
localhost:2241/Samsung/Page2

How Can I Solve This

ProductController.cs

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductRepository repository;  
    public ProductController(IProductRepository repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }
    public ViewResult List(int? page, string category)
    {
        ProductListViewModel model = new ProductListViewModel
        {
            Prodcuts = repository.Products
                .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category),
            CurrentCategory = category
        };
        return View (model.Prodcuts.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 3));
    }
}
```

List.cshtml

```
@model IPagedList<OnlineShoppingStore.Domain.Entities.Product>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
....
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("ProductSummary",p)
}
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("List", new {page }))
```

ProductListViewModel.cs

```
public class ProductListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable <Product> Prodcuts { get; set; } 
    public string CurrentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

What Should I do ??

Comment: the post edited with full code .. I am not professional and still learning MVC so Please tell me where I can edit or add the code .. I done what you said before `category = Model.CurrentCategory` .. and `@model IPagedList<OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI.Models.ProductListViewModel>`  but still not working .. please write a code not explaining .. I appreciate that .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**ProductController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using OnlineShoppingStore.Domain.Abstract;
using PagedList;
using PagedList.Mvc;
using OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI.Models;



namespace OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }
    public ViewResult List(int? page, string category, string Filter_Value)
    {

        if (category != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            category = Filter_Value;
        }

        ViewBag.FilterValue = category;

        ProductListViewModel model = new ProductListViewModel
        {
            Prodcuts = repository.Products
                .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category),
            CurrentCategory = category

        };


                 return View (model.Prodcuts.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 3));

           }


       }
 }
```

**ProductListViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using OnlineShoppingStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI.Models
{
public class ProductListViewModel
{
    public  IEnumerable <Product> Prodcuts { get; set; } 
    public  string CurrentCategory { get; set; }

}
}
```

**List.cshtml**

```
@model IPagedList<OnlineShoppingStore.Domain.Entities.Product>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

@foreach (var p in Model)
{
@Html.Partial("ProductSummary",p)

}

@{

}
<div>

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("List", new {page,      Filter_Value = ViewBag.FilterValue }))


Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
```